# Define Same-site cookie in web.xml cookie-config for Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, cookies

I would want to add the [Same-site cookie attribute](https://caniuse.com/#feat=same-site-cookie-attribute) to the cookie I'm using in a Tomcat web app, to add the HttpOnly attribute it was enough adding the following definition in the web.xml file :

```
   <session-config>
    <session-timeout>240</session-timeout>
    <cookie-config>
        <http-only>true</http-only>
    </cookie-config>
  </session-config>
```

What about the Same-site attribute? Is it possible to set it in the same way as the http-only, like : `<same-site>true</same-site>` ?

A definition of the Same-site cookie :

> Same-site cookies (née "First-Party-Only" (née "First-Party")) allow
>   servers to mitigate the risk of CSRF and information leakage attacks
>   by asserting that a particular cookie should only be sent with
>   requests initiated from the same registrable domain.

Comment: [Ivan Tsenov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57622508/1606632) wrote how it can be added to Tomcat's `context.xml`.

Answer (score 5):

The options for the `web.xml` configuration file are defined in the [Java Servlet Specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr315/index.html). This file does not support options for including the [`SameSite` in the cookies](https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained/).

---

### A Simple Configuration for Tomcat

If you wanna add the `SameSite` option to the cookies in your application, you can configure the [Tomcat Cookie Processor](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/cookie-processor.html) (the `CookieProcessor`) in the `META-INF/context.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>

    <!-- Add SameSite to the cookies --> 
    <CookieProcessor 
        sameSiteCookies="none" />

</Context>
```

**NOTE:** This configuration may fail in older versions of Tomcat. Apparently, these options work well if you use, at least, Tomcat 8.5.48 or 9.0.28. For older versions, there are some [workarounds you may check](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/DEV/Tomcat+and+Jetty+SameSite+Workarounds).

---

### Other options

You may try some web filters that implement this behaviour. For instance, you may check the [IdP SameSite Session Cookie Filter](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/DEV/IdP+SameSite+Filter+Implementation).

Comment: Adding on an alternative scenario for future viewers: For some reason WEB-INF/ folder wasn't working for me so I added an application specific context with samesite cookies in the tomcat conf folder.  Assuming it's >= Tomcat 9.0.21. link: https://octopus.com/blog/defining-tomcat-context-paths